# Am I correctly using the conditional probability notation in this problem?

Tags: probability, self-learning, conditional-probability

**Problem**: Two numbers are chose at random from among the numbers 1 to 10 without replacement.

**Goal**: Find the probability that the second number chosen is 5.

**Official Solution**:
$A_{i}:i \in \left\{1,2,...,10\right\}$ is event that first number chosen is $i$. $B$ is the event that second number chosen is 5. Use the **total probability law** to get: $$\begin{equation}P(B)=\sum_{i=1}^{10}P(B|A_{i})P(A_{i}) = 9 \, \frac{1}{9} \, \frac{1}{10}=\frac{1}{10}\end{equation}$$

**My Solution**:$$\begin{equation*}P(B|A_{i}) = \frac{n(B)}{n(S)} = \frac{9}{9 \cdot 10} = \frac{1}{10}\end{equation*}$$

**Question**: How can we at all write $P(B)$? Is probability for event $B$ not inherently conditional? You can't choose the second number without choosing the first number, so how could one write anything other than $P(B|A)$?

Comment: Any further questions?

Answer (score 1):

You are asked to evaluate the probability that the second number chosen is $5$. This is clearly $P(B)$. There is no condition mentioned.

Yes you are right that you cannot choose a second number without having chosen the first number. But $P(B)$ this is the probability that the second chosen number is $5$ regardless which number is chosen first. You must choose a first number, but it is irrelevant which one.

---

For this purpose the law of total probabilty is used. For instance

$P(B|A_1)$ is the probability that the second number is a $5$ given that the first number is $1$.

The number $1$ has been already drawn first. 9 numbers still can be secelcted. Number 5 is still among these numbers. Thus  $P(B|A_1)=\frac19$

$P(A_1)$ is the probability that number 1 is selected first is $\frac1{10}$.

Thus $P(B\cap A_1)=P(B|A_1)\cdot P(A_1)=\frac{1}{90}$

The probability $P(B\cap A_i)$ are all $\frac{1}{90}$ except for $i=5$. $P(B\cap A_5)=0$

Thus $P(B)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10} P(B|A_i)\cdot P(A_i)$

$=\frac1{90}+\frac1{90}+\frac1{90}+\frac1{90}+0+\frac1{90}+\frac1{90}+\frac1{90}+\frac1{90}+\frac1{90}+\frac1{90}=\frac{9}{90}$

---

P(B) can be calculated more easily.  To draw a 5 secondly it must not be drawn at the first draw. $P(\overline A_5)=\frac9{10}$.

$\overline A_5$ is the complementary event of $A_5$. This it the event that $5$ is not chosen first. And $P(B|\overline A_5)=\frac19$. This is the probabilty that number 5 is chosen secondly with the condition that 5  is not chosen first. Using the total law of probability:

$P(B)=(B|\overline A_5)\cdot P(\overline A_5)+(B| A_5)\cdot P( A_5)=\frac19\cdot  \frac{9}{10}+0\cdot \frac1{10}=\frac1{10}$

I cannot really comprehend what do you mean by $n(B)$ and $n(S)$. And how you got the numbers for them ?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

> **Question**: How can we at all write $P(B)$? Is probability for event $B$ not inherently conditional? You can't choose the second number without choosing the first number, so how could one write anything other than $P(B|A)$?

First thought experiment: 
Lottery with tickets 1 through 10.  A mediator picks two of the lottery tickets.  He then arbitrarily chooses one of the two tickets and places it in Envelope-1.  He then places the other ticket in Envelope-2.  Clearly, the chance of the ticket-5 being in Envelope-1 is the same as the chance of the ticket-5 being in Envelope-2.

Second thought experiment: 
Same as the first, but instead, the mediator picks the two numbers one at a time.  The first number picked goes in Envelope-1.  The second number picked goes in Envelope-2.  The analysis is identical to the first thought experiment.  It doesn't matter whether Envelope-1 contains the first ticket (re second thought experiment) or whether it is 50-50 whether Envelope-1 contains the first ticket or the second ticket (re first thought experiment).

Therefore, the problem can be reduced to the probability of drawing a 5 on the first draw.  Therefore, without involving any conditional probabilities, $p(B) = \frac{1}{10}.$

**However**, the only way to utilize the above approach is to **first** develop your intuition to the point that you are **absolutely certain** that my approach is valid.

**Addendum**
Justifying the analysis from a different perspective.

The tickets 1 thru 10 are lined up in a row.  Then the mediator randomly assigns a number 1 thru 10 (without replacement) to each ticket.  The assigned number represents when the ticket will be drawn.

That is, if the ticket-5 is assigned the number 1, it will be drawn first.  If the ticket-5 is assigned the number 2, it will be drawn second.

The ticket-5 is equally likely to be assigned the number 1 as it is to be assigned the number 2.  Therefore, from this alternate perspective, (again) the chance of ticket-5 being drawn second is the same as the chance of ticket-5 being drawn first.